# Relation b/w venation and transpiration

Tags: botany, plant-physiology

What purpose does reticulate venation in dorsiventral leaf or parallel venation in isobilateral leaf serve?

Does it have any relation with unequal transpiration in dorsiventral leaf or equal transpiration in isobilateral leaf?